# what does this xpath mean?

Tags: xpath

```
//p[not(ancestor::*[3])]
  //table[ancestor::*[1][self::p] or ancestor::*[2][self::p]]
    tr/td//a[ancestor::*[1`][self::td] or ancestor::*[2][self::td]]
```

Comment: Perhaps it means you need to find an alternative way to locate that paragraph since the xpath is so convoluted.

Comment: @Brian Donovan - The expression selects `a` tags.

Comment: @Oded: Right you are, didn't scroll all the way over :) Except that it's not well-formed as far as I can tell. This part looks like it needs a `//` before the `tr`: `...[self::p]]tr/td//a...`.

Comment: @Brian Donovan - You are quite right.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
//                               # from the root node, look at all descendants
p[                               # select nodes of type <p>, who have…
  not(ancestor::*[3])            #   …no ancestor 3 levels up
]                                #
//                               # from these nodes, select descendants
table[                           # of type <table>, who have…
  ancestor::*[1][self::p]        #   …a <p> as their direct ancestor
  or                             #   or
  ancestor::*[2][self::p]        #   …a <p> as their second ancestor
]                                # 
                                 # syntax error, this should be a location step
tr                               # …select all nodes of type <tr>
/                                # from their children…
td                               # …select all nodes of type <td>
//                               # from their descendants…
a[                               # …select all nodes of type <a>, who have
  ancestor::*[1][self::td]       #   …a <td> as their direct ancestor   
  or                             #   or 
  ancestor::*[2][self::td]       #   …a <td> as their second ancestor
]
```

Or, expressed in HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      <table>
        <tr> 
          <td>
            <a title="These would be selected." />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The whole XPath does not make too much sense anyway. It goes without saying that `<p><table>` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Lets break this down:

```
//p[not(ancestor::*[3])]
```

Selects all `p` tags who do not have a 3rd ancestor.

In those:

```
//table[ancestor::*[1][self::p] or ancestor::*[2][self::p]]
```

It selects all `table` tags whose first or second ancestor is a `p` tag.

Then:

```
tr/td//a[ancestor::*[1`][self::td] or ancestor::*[2][self::td]]
```

This isn't entirely correct (there should be a `/` at the start). However, it goes down the `tr/td//`s to select all `a` tags whose first or second ancestor is a `td` tag.

---

All and all, it is very convoluted and could probably be a lot easier to achieve with some `id` attributes defined in the relevant places.

Comment: Having written a fair number of xpaths for the purpose of screen scraping, I'd say this one is horribly broken. Not only was it not well-formed, but it's incredibly fragile. It'd break at the slightest change to the page.

Answer (score 1):

The XPath expression you specified:

```
//p[not(ancestor::*[3])]
     //table[ancestor::*[1][self::p] or ancestor::*[2][self::p]]
           tr/td//a
```

isn't syntactically legal -- it is missing a `/` before the `tr`.

**The corrected XPath expression**:

```
//p[not(ancestor::*[3])]
     //table[ancestor::*[1][self::p] or ancestor::*[2][self::p]]
           /tr/td//a
```

**was provided as answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567066/top-down-or-bottom-up-approach-to-search-elements-on-a-html-dom-document/4567777#4567777) question**.

As explained in the linked (above) answer, the meaning is:

*This selects all a elements whose parent or grand-parent is td, whose parent is a tr, whose parent is a table, whose parent or grandparent is a `p` that has less than 3 ancesstor - elements*

The OP wanted a way to get the `a` elements that can be located under a `p` buried not deeper than 3 levels beneath the root of the document, then under a `table/tr/td` where the `table` is buried at a level not greater than 3 from the `p`.

**Certainly, wanting to select such nodes may not seem too-meaningful**, but we are in no position to judge anyone's needs and requirements.

**The amazing fact is that XPath is so powerful to satisfy even such requirements.**

Comment: A minor: Isn't `ancestor::*[1][self::p]` equal to `parent::p`? It looks like you'd used that to make the expression readable...

Comment: @Alejandro: Exactly, this is for the user to see the pattern (`ancesstor::*[N][self::p]`), so I think uniformness is helpful here. BTW, Happy New Year!  :)

Comment: Thanks! And happy New Year to you, too!