# How do I find a specific text within an xml page and navigate to that webpage or at least return the URL?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping

I have the following xml table from a sitemap.xml url (image attached):
[sitemap.xml file from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1YvN.png)

I am trying to parse out from the xml the URL by searching for these two criterias if they exist in that URL:

1. "Average-Weather-in-"
2. "-Year-Round"

Then return the URL

so in this case I'd be expecting a URL of https://weatherspark.com/y/8004/Average-Weather-in-Austin-Texas-United-States-Year-Round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be using XML/HTML parser such as [`beautifulsoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# change to your URL:
url = 'https://weatherspark.com/sitemap-271.xml'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'xml')

for loc in soup.select('loc'):
    text = loc.text
    if 'Average-Weather-in-' in text and '-Year-Round' in text:
        print(text)
```

Prints:

```
...

https://weatherspark.com/y/138371/Average-Weather-in-Mulanay-Philippines-Year-Round
https://weatherspark.com/y/138372/Average-Weather-in-Mangero-Philippines-Year-Round
https://weatherspark.com/y/138373/Average-Weather-in-Malibago-Philippines-Year-Round
https://weatherspark.com/y/138374/Average-Weather-in-Madulao-Philippines-Year-Round
https://weatherspark.com/y/138375/Average-Weather-in-Macalelon-Philippines-Year-Round

...
```

Comment: I just learned about CSS selectors to use in the
soup.select() method

However I can't find 'loc' from the CSS selectors, care to explain?
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php

Answer (score 1):

To find a specific part of HTML or XML documents you can parse them into a [DOM data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and then traverse it programmatically.
Even better, you can use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to find specific parts efficiently.

See also

- https://towardsdatascience.com/xpath-for-python-89f4423415e0
- [XPath syntax with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647973/xpath-syntax-with-python)
- [How to use XPath in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xsl to transform the XML would use contains(), which takes 2 parameters - the XPath to the target and the text that you are looking for

```
<xsl:value-of select="contains('url/loc','Average-Weather-in')" />
```

This will return the url.